# How to update Directus CMS manually: problem with "field" (text input), v8.3.0

Tags: php, directus

I have updated Directus to version v8.3.0, but when trying to add a new "field" to an existing "collection", the server returns error 403, and before everything worked correctly.

What will I be doing wrong? Should I execute any command manually?

I do not have access to the command line, it is a shared server.

If I choose the type "Text Input, Text-Area or WYSIWYG" it returns error 403, if I choose "Toggle", it works correctly. The strange thing is that other types of "fields" do work.

Comment: HTTP 403 Forbidden is an anauthorised message. check the network panel, does it call different URL's depending if that thing is checked or not?

Comment: Do you have access to your logs (PHP, MySQL Apache, or Directus)? They should contain additional details about that 403 error that could help you, or others, debug.

Comment: no, but I will check to access them

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**
Using an [RC Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate) is probably not a good idea for production as it's simply a Beta. I suggest upgrating to a supported version, the latest version is [v8.3.0](https://github.com/directus/directus/releases/tag/v8.3.0)

**Note:**
You also noted "before everything worked correctly", such a sentence is not much help when we don't know what your setup was "before", were you on v7? As there are breaking changes between major versions.